# Formatting one-sided error bars in Mathematica 12

Tags: plotting

Below is a plot I made in MATLAB.

[image: MATLAB Error Bar Plot]

I need to recreate the above plot in Mathematica. This is what I'm able to achieve on Mathematica 12.2 (the slight formatting differences compared to the MATLAB plot are intentional):

[image: Mathematica Error Bar Plot]

As we can see, the plot in Mathematica has a non-zero "fence width" on top of each plot marker whereas the plot made in MATLAB does not. Is there any way to achieve error bars as shown in the MATLAB plot using Mathematica?

If we assume the x-coordinates are stored in `xData`, the y-coordinates in `yData`, and the tops of the error bars in `yMaxData` (all vectors of the same length), the code I use in Mathematica to generate this plot (ignoring all the formatting) is:

```
linePlotData1 = Table[{xData[[ii, 1]], Around[yData[[ii, jj]], {0, yMaxData[[ii, jj]]}]}, {jj, 1, numCols}, {ii, 1, numRows}];
```

where `numCols` is 2 in this case and `numRows` is 10 (the length of the data vectors).

To generate the plot, I use `ListPlot[linePlotData1]` with `ScalingFunctions` set to `{"Log", "Log"}` and various other formatting-related commands including `IntervalMarkersStyle` to format the thickness and color of the error bars. However, I wasn't able to find any documentation regarding whether or not I can format the positive and negative directions of the error bars differently.

**Is there a way to do this, preferably without having to use any external packages?**

For example, can I set `IntervalMarkers` to "Bars" for the negative and "Fences" for the positive directions, respectively? The documentation doesn't seem to have any information on whether or not doing so is possible. I tried something like `IntervalMarkers -> {{"Bars","Fences"},{"Bars","Fences"}}` (repeated twice for each of the two data "columns"), but this threw an error.

Thanks!

Comment: does `ListPlot[data]/. Line[pat:{{_List,_Offset}..}]:>Line[pat[[;;2]]]` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr Yes! That's perfect! Thanks so much! I'll admit that I don't quite understand the code (i.e., why it works). So if you have the time and wouldn't mind explaining further (even in the form of an answer if you think it would be useful to the community), that would be very helpful. I'd of course readily accept your answer should you choose to write one. :)

Comment: Rahul, posted the comment as an answer with some explanation of how/why it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{1, Around[5, 2]}, {2, Around[4, 1]}, {3, Around[5, 1]}};

lp = ListPlot[data, IntervalMarkersStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

If we inspect the `Line` primitives in `lp`

```
Cases[lp, _Line, All] // Column
```

[image]

we find that the fences for a data point are implemented as a `Line` object with 4 pieces using `Offset` coordinates (the first two pieces are the top fence and the last two pieces are the bottom fence.) So we can post-process `lp` to remove the bottom fences (that is, take the first two pieces of the `Line` object) to get the desired look:

```
lp /. Line[pat : {{_List, _Offset} ..}] :> Line[pat[[;; 2]]]
```

[image]